# Baixar ficheiros com cordova armazenados na base dados

Tags: php, android, mysql, apache-cordova

Existe alguma forma de baixar documentos armazenados numa base de dados `mysql`, no meu `aplicativo híbrido cordova`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Existe mais de uma forma para efetuar esse processo, mas o mais simples é a criação de um Web Service.

O que você precisa fazer é escolher uma linguagem de programação Web que tenha conhecimento e utilizar ela para conversar (buscar os dados) do banco de dados. Depois dentro de sua aplicação você utiliza JavaScript para fazer as solicitações desses dados. Simples requisções HTTP's já devem resolver, mas lembre-se de **CORS**, que sempre causa problemas em aplicações Cordova.